# wordpress custom query and orderby

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to query posts using custom meta fields (date) and order them by the custom meta field (start_date).

I need to look for posts that start on or after todays date or end after today's date.

It all seems to work apart from the order by start date and OR statement, any help appreciated.

```
<?php 

$today = date('y-m-d');



$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'start_date',
     'orderby' => 'meta_value',
       'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'start_date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'end_date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>'
        )
    )
);

query_posts( $args );

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are MySQL database for wordpress and date format should be `YYYYMMDD`.

Update date format: use `$today = date('Y-m-d');` in stead of  `$today = date('y-m-d');`

Also `type=>date` in `meta_query` like below:

```
$args = array(
'numberposts'   => -1,
'meta_key'      => 'start_date',
'orderby'       => 'meta_value',
'order'         => 'ASC',
'meta_query'    => array(
    'relation'  => 'OR',
    array(
        'key'       => 'start_date',
        'value'     => $today,
        'type'      => 'date',
        'compare'   => '>='
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => 'end_date',
        'value'     => $today,
        'type'      => 'date',
        'compare'   => '>'
    )
)
);
```

Hope will help!

Comment: +1, also, for `WP-3.7` there is a [date_query](http://heera.it/advanced-date-queries-wordpress-3-7).